# Display UTC datetime that is converted to web user's local time

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC project, and the MVC controller pass a view model that has a UTC datetime property. I want on the MVC View page, the Utc datetime converted to web user's local date time depending on his time zone.

Details:
Assume the `MyViewModel.Utc` property has value of `8/7/2022 6:00:00 PM` that is passed from server side. What I expect for web user to see:

- When a web user who sits in Central Standard Time zone, he should see
  the display result as `8/7/2022 1:00:00 PM`.
- When a web user who
  sits in Eastern Standard Time zone, he should see the display result
  as `8/7/2022 2:00:00 PM`.

The following is what I am trying to do on the MVC view page cshtml:

```
@model MyViewModel

<div>  
        <dd>           
            @DateTime.Parse(Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Utc).ToString()).ToLocalTime().ToString()
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

*Question 1:* Is that the correct way to do?

*Question 2:* How can I test my page with different time zones?

Thank you.

Comment: ToLocalTime() will be fetching Server's local time. That wont work based on User's timezone.  I have achieved this using jQuery to find local timezone offset ( from GMT in minutes) of the user via his browser(var d = new Date(); var offset= d.getTimezoneOffset();), The only way to test this is to set your system clock to different timezones and then check